# Modification in symbolic link

Tags: java, file, symlink

How to identify which link modified the target file when multiple symbolic link exists for a single file using Java? I was unable to find which file modified the target file.

Example: `D:\sample.txt,D:\folder1\sample.txt`; these two are links. The target file is located in `E:\sample.txt`.

Now how to identify whether `D:\sample.txt` or `D:\folder1\sample.txt` modified the `E:\sample.txt`?

Comment: "I want the code" <-- SO is not a free coding service!

Answer (score 1):

> How to identify which link modified the target file when multiple symbolic link exists for a single file using java?

It is not possible.

It is not possible in *any* programming language.

This functionality would have to be supported by the operating system, and no operating system I've ever come across does.

---

There are heuristics (using timestamps) that will probably work "most of the time", but in each case there are circumstances under which the heuristic will give no answer or even the wrong answer.  Here are some of the confounding issues:

With simple timestamp heuristics:

- it won't if either of the symlinks is on a read-only file system, or a file system where access times are not recorded (e.g. depending on mount options), and
- it won't work if a file read occurs on the symlink after the last file write.

When you add a watcher:

- it won't work if you weren't "watching" at the time (duh!), and
- it won't work if you have too many watcher events ... and you can't keep up.

(Besides, I don't think you can get events on the use of a symlink.  So you would still need to check the symlink access timestamps anyway.  And that means that read-only file systems, etc are a problem here too.)

And then there are scenarios like:

- *both* symlinks are used to write the file,
- you don't know about all of the symlinks, or
- the symlink used for writing has been deleted or "touched".

These are probably beyond of the scope of the OP's use-case.  But they are relevant to the general question as set out by the OP's first sentence.

Comment: Disagree; When "dereferencing" a symlink under Linux, the last access time of the symlink is modified. And with Java 7 you _can_ detect that.

Comment: But that doesn't tell you which link was used to *modify* the file; e.g. if one link was used to modify, and *then* the second one was used to access it.

Comment: It can if the last access time of a link is comparably greater than the last access time of the other -- but as I said in my answer, this is not a guarantee anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do that using [`Files.readAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Class-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-). The below works *with Linux*, since when you "use" a symlink under Linux, its last access time is modified. No idea under Windows, you'll have to test.

If `symlink1` is a `Path` to your first symlink and `symlink2` a `Path` to your second symlink, and `realFile` a `Path` to your real file, then you can retrieve [`FileTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html) objects of the last access time for both symlinks and last modification time of the file using:

```
Files.readAttributes(symlink1, BasicFileAttributes.class).lastAccessTime();
Files.readAttributes(symlink2, BasicFileAttributes.class).lastAccessTime(); 
Files.readAttributes(realFile, BasicFileAttributes.class).lastModifiedTime();
```

Since `FileTime` is `Comparable` to itself, you *may* spot which symlink is modified but this is NOT a guarantee.

Explanation: if someone uses `symlink1` to modify `realFile`, then the *access time* of `symlink1` will be modified and the *modification time* of `realFile` will be modified. If the last access time of `symlink1` is GREATER than the last access time of `symlink2`, then there is *a possibility* that `symlink1` was used for this operation; on the other hand, if the last access time of `symlink2` is greater *and* the last modification time of `realFile` is lesser, then you are sure that `symlink2` was *not* used for this purpose.

But again there is no REAL guarantee. Those are only heuristics!

---

You should also have a look at using a `WatchService` in order to watch for modifications on the real file; this would make the heuristics above more precise even. But again, no guarantee.

Comment: There is not sufficient information there to determine the answer in all cases; e.g. if the file is being accessed as well.

Comment: Look: what if `atime(symlink1) < mtime(realFile) < atime(symlink2)`? It would then be logical that _IF_ a symlink was used to _modify_ `realFile`, it would have been `symlink1`.

Comment: You are conflating lastAccessed and lastModified times.  If you don't do that, it is clear that there are scenarios where your logic cannot give the correct answer.  That's because modifying a file does not modify the symlink.  It only accesses it.

Comment: I don't! Look at what I said -- when you use a symlink under Linux you _modify its access time_!

Comment: But you don't modify its modification time!!!  In other words, if you look at the symlink, you cannot distinguish a target access and a target modification.  So for example, if a target access happens via both links after the last target modification (via either) you cannot tell whence the modification came.

Comment: No but the OP wants to know whether the _target file_ has been modified! Read my answer carefully again

Comment: But the OP does not say that the file hasn't ALSO been accessed.  I fully understand your answer.  It does not work in all cases.  I've now explained a case in which it does not work.  And I think you are even acknowledging this in your answer.

Comment: I never said it worked in all cases ;) But hey, this demonstrates the power of the new file API which is grossly underused so I'll help in any way I can :p

Comment: *"I never said it worked in all cases ;)"* ... Erm.  Doesn't your first comment dispute my first comment??? :-)

Comment: Well, I make a difference between "cannot be done" and "you can do that but success is not guaranteed" ;)

Comment: But I didn't use those words ... in the comment you were responding to.

Comment: This becomes a play on words here, but your answer starts with "it is not possible". This is admitting defeat without even trying :p No offense meant, of course ;)